# What does the presence of rsAccessDenied mean?

Tags: security, ssrs

I'm troubleshooting a SSRS security issue where one user is being denied access, while another user with apparently identical settings is working as expected.

I'm seeing "The permissions granted to user 'mydomain\myAccount' are insufficient for performing this operation" in the browser, but curiously NOT seeing the (rsAccessDenied) at the end.

Is this indicative of something that can help me troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check the rights to the folder and report in SSRS. You can do this in the "Security" option under the "Folder Settings" menu. Click "Edit Item Security" and provide your user(s) with the correct rights and permissions.